# Machine learning - Categorize free text in blocks

Tags: algorithm, text, machine-learning, match, artificial-intelligence

How to use machine learning algorithm/technique to divide free text in different blocks or Subjects/attributes?

For example; Resume/CVs, the approach, would help to divide the CVs into the different blocks: profile, education, experience to mention but a few and also to know which blocks are linked to which topic? A model could be training based on existing CVs/Resume.

I'm not sure if this is a good approach and I'm not sure which classifier/solution to use.

Comment: Cool question for starters.and i would kindly request you to also join [artificial  intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com) and [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) for further research and learning